# Show heteroskedasticity

Tags: maximum-likelihood, heteroscedasticity, bernoulli-distribution

**Setup**: Consider a random sample of size n with binary outcome $Y_i\in\{0,1\}$. Assume $Y_i\sim Bern(\pi_i)$. Use a linear probability model so that $\pi_i=X_i^\intercal\beta$, where $X_i$ is a predictor vector of length P. Here consider $\beta$ by maximum likelihood.

**Question**: Show that the error term from the linear regression of $Y_i$ on $X_i$ is always heteroskedastic. If you were to use OLS for this model, would this problem be corrected?

**Comment**: The error term is heteroskedastic if it depends on $X_i$, but I'm not sure what approach I should use to get a formula for it.

Comment: If you used OLS, you could pretend you have homoskedasticity, but, with a binomial outcome, you know you have heteroskedasticity. Thus, if you use a LPM, ML estimates would be efficient while OLS wouldn't. The advantage of using OLS relies on the fact you could avoid convergence issues and get an estimate anyway. Nevertheless, such estimate could include values outside the range of admissible ones (0-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heteroskedasticity means: *the variance* of the error term depends on $X$. In our case
$$
Var[\varepsilon_i] = Var[Y_i] = \pi_i(1 - \pi_i) = X_i^T\beta(1 - X_i^T\beta). 
$$
So we have dependence of $Var[\varepsilon_i] $ on $X_i$... In general, memorize definitions before attempting anything.

Comment: Does $var(e_i)=var(Y_I)$ because $Y_i=f(X_i^\intercal\beta)+\epsilon_i$ for this model basically? But the $f$ isn't obviously derived in this case.

Comment: You said: "linear model". Therefore, $f(x) = x$. But that is not very important. $Var[\varepsilon_i] = Var[Y_i]$ because $X_i$ is assumed to be deterministic. If $X_i$ is random, we should be talking about $Var[\varepsilon_i | X_i] = Var[Y_i | X_i]$.